# What insulation should I use in my attached garage?

Tags: drywall, insulation, moisture, winterizing

I'm currently tearing out the sheetrock and everything in my attached garage to do general repairs to other things. I quickly found that there wasn't a single bit of insulation (which explains a lot on my heat bills in the winter I'm sure) so I'm going to do that too before I re-drywall everything.

My plan is faced r-19 in the walls (with the face towards the interior) and non-faced r-30 for the ceiling between the floor joists since there's bedrooms above it.

**Question is**, am I assuming the correct types (R19/R30) for this project, and do I have any airflow concerns (venting) I should address from doing this?

I live in the Midwest US and we can get some pretty cold winters, the garage doors are insulated types and the place is sealed pretty decent. There's another rear entry door and a door into the home, both have decent sealing on them and I just replaced the exterior door last year, it will be used daily once completed so I can't assume any "stail air" or excess moisture would get bottled up in there for too long at a time.

Any insight?

Comment: What size studs and joists do you have?

Comment: Cellulose does a much better job IMPE (and I've used both.)

Comment: @rjbergen The floor joists (ceiling) are 2x12's standard 16" spacing, the walls are 2x4 standard spacing

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'd agree, but I dont have the equipment to spray it, and I thought it was a bit more expensive when you buy those sheets, we don't plan on staying in the house forever so cutting costs where I can also. I'll have to go research a little to see if there's any cost benefit etc.

Comment: To what extent is the garage heated or cooled?  Are there exposed water pipes in the garage or in the garage walls?

Comment: Could you post more information about the insulation you plan to use? I'm not sure how you're figuring R19 in a 2"x4" stud bay. That seems higher than what I'm familiar with for fiberglass batts. R30 for a 2"x12" joist space also seems low. http://www.greatdayimprovements.com/insulation-r-value-chart.aspx

Comment: @wallyk There is one vent in the ceiling that generally stays shut but there are ducts out to it, which is one of the things I was repairing while doing all this to patch some leaks on it. There's H/C lines for washer/dryer in an interior wall but I've already got those well insulated from a previous project so not worried about them at all.

Comment: @rjbergen I'm in Zone 4 with a brand new furnace, I'll be the first to admit I'm no pro in the insulation rating department but it seemed like a general good fit, the R19 fit perfect and was the highest rated I'd used in that type of space previously, plus I can get deals on the owens/corning R19 so it was a cost effect choice also, the R30 I was thinking because it's just between floors and nothing of it is insulating exterior. Should I be thinking something else?

Comment: I'm not an insulation pro either. I wasn't aware that R19 was available for a 2"x4" stud bay. If it is, that's great. R30 for the ceiling is good for interior. For some reason I was thinking more attic above a heated room. I forgot it was a garage with bedrooms above.

Comment: Cellulose blowing equipment is a standard rental item. I wonder if you're confusing it with plastic foams, when you mention sheets? For an open-wall install, get a quote on having it done via damp-spray (that equipment is not generally available for rent - hire a pro for that part)

Comment: @Ecnerwal yea, I was trying to avoid rentals and hiring anyone, I prefer to do it myself and we won't be in the house more than a few more years tops so trying to keep the costs down. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cellulose insulation would be a great choice if you have living quarters above.  The cellulose insulation is more dense and will help control air movement and drafts.  [Cellulose Insulation](http://avalancheinsulation.com/cellulose-insulation-blown-cellulose-insulation-houston-woodlands-spring-conroe-huntsville-kingwood-humble-atascocita-tomball)

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as the correct answer as that's what I should have done, however I've already done it with fiberglass because I was able to get it very cheap for this project.